# How to prove 1/(1*2)+1/(2*3) + … + 1/((2n-1)(2n)) = 1/(n+1) + 1/(n+2) + … + 1/(2n) by induction?

Tags: induction

[Basically, the expression in a task looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poJHM.png)

[I've made a thesis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZtw4.png)

Then I use an assumption, to change some part of thesis:

[I replaced the red part with a right side of an assumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk350.png)

Then I substracted parts, which was the same in both sides of the equation, and got this:

[Finally equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GgCW.png)

But this equation isn't true, it gives a 1 = 0
What should I change? Did I something wrong with thesis?

Comment: What does $\frac1{1\times2}+\frac1{1\times3}+\cdots+\frac1{(2n-1)(2n)}$ *mean*? If you put $n=1$ in $\frac1{(2n-1)(2n)}$, then you get indeed $\frac1{1\times2}$, but if you put $n=2$ there, then what you get is $\frac1{3\times4}$, not $\frac1{1\times3}$.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake, now it's correct, thank you.

Comment: My answer was an attempt to address the original version of the problem. The new one makes no sense either. Do you mean for the final term on the left to be $\frac{1}{n(2n-1)}$?

Comment: Could you check this once again, please?

Comment: @Tetris570 Who do you want to check what? My answer obtains the only way to write the right-hand side in the form $\sum_{k=1}^na_k$.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing $n$ from $k$ to $k+1$ adds $\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}$ to the right-hand side, which is $0$ if $n=0$ as it's a sum of $n$ terms. Therefore, it's $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k(2k-1)}$, so the original problem has a misprint (the $\frac13$ should be $\frac{1}{12}$).